# "Contributed to", "contributed for", or "start to"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I just want to know if this sentence is right:

> It **contributed to** the decision of start respecting people.

If it's not, how can I fix it? I've no idea if I should use ***contributed for*** or ***start to*** instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say:

> It contributed to the decision **to start** respecting people.

*It contributed to the decision* is fine. What was the decision? *to start respecting people*.